# Mockito vs @Configurable

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to write JUnit tests for some code that is normally managed with Spring.

Let's say I have this:

```
@Configurable
public class A {
  @Autowired MyService service;

  public void callA() { service.doServiceThings(); }
}
```

I can write a test for this class using Mockito and PowerMock like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ATest {
  @Spy MyService service = new MyService();

  @Before void initMocks() { MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); }

  @Test void test() {
    @InjectMocks A a = new A(); // injects service into A
    a.callA();
    //assert things
  }
}
```

But now I run into a case when some other class constructs instances of A:

```
public class B {
  public void doSomething() {
    A a = new A(); // service is injected by Spring
    a.callA();
  }
}
```

How do I make service get injected into instances of A created inside a B method?

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class BTest {
  @Spy MyService service = new MyService();

  @Before void initMocks() { MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); }

  @Test testDoSomething() {
     B b = new B();
     // is there a way to cause service to be injected when the method calls new A()?
     b.doSomething(); 
     // assert things
  }
}
```

Comment: Not easily, and this is an excellent argument against field injection. You will probably need to use a Spring test context.

Answer (score 0):

Field injection is bad but still there's one thing that you can do to easily stub that A instantiation (or maybe I misunderstood sth). Make B have an AFactory injected via constructor.

```
public class B {
    private final AFactory aFactory;
    public B(AFactory aFactory) {
        this.aFactory=aFactory;
    }
    public void doSomething() {
    A a = aFactory.getA();
    a.callA();
    }
}
```

And then you can create a Mock of aFactory and inject it to B via constructor.